# Composite selectors in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to select all radio buttons with a certain name but not having a certain value, like this:

```
$('input[type="radio"][name="myname"][value!="myvalue"]')
```

, but this does not work.

How do I do it properly with a single selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work. To use a single selector you would need to provide a class that specified the three attributes, and then select on that class.

Comment: Don't know why didn't it work in the first place, now when I tried again it worked. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 3):

This looks right for me. You could change from

```
$('input[type="radio"][name="myname"][value!="myvalue"]')
```

to

```
$('input:radio[name="myname"][value!="myvalue"]')
```

but that should nothing change.

Try step by step to find out what does not work, like:

```
alert($('input').length);
alert($('input[type="radio"]').length);
alert($('input[type="radio"][name="myname"]').length);
alert($('input[type="radio"][name="myname"][value!="myvalue"]').length);
```